# resize an image using custom process

Tags: image, perl

I have created a little subroutine and want to know what needs to be added to it in order to resize an image of pretty much any type (obscure types excluded):

```
######################
sub printImage($) {
  # be sure to do your error checking BEFORE calling this. it'll just
  # blindly rip along.
  my $fn = $_[0];
  my $type = getType($fn); # see sub below
  my $buffer = "";

  print "content-type: image/$type\n"; # these are awful, but ok for now
  print "\n"; # separate just in case we want to add more to the header.

  binmode STDOUT;

  open my $FH, "<", $fn or die "$!";
  while (read ($FH, $buffer, 10240)) {
    print $buffer; # prefer NOT to print as I read...
  }
  close $FH;

  # return $OUTPUT; # this would be better, no?
}
```

the "getType" simply looks at the filename extension, and returns the extension.

what i want to know is how to resize the image using the above function.  i do not want to install any extra modules, or packages, or do anything like that.

Comment: By "not want[ing] to install any extra modules, or packages, or do anything like that." you are essentially making this impossible.

Comment: ok  is GD not pure perl, then?  I don't have a clue about it's internals.  i just use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function does not manipulate image content, and cannot easily be converted to do so. Resizing an image is much more complicated than this.

Since you've specifically requested that we not recommend additional modules, I have nothing to offer. Resizing an image in pure Perl code would be prohibitively slow, and would require far more code than I could possibly include in an answer. If you want to perform manipulations on image content, such as resizing images, use an image manipulation module such as [GD](https://metacpan.org/pod/GD) or [Image::Magick](https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::Magick).

Comment: I wasn't looking for easy.  GD does it....I asked cuz the free host I use doesn't have and won't install packages....

Comment: Free hosting is… well, you get what you pay for. Perl is particularly useless if you can't install modules; get a real web host.

Comment: lol.  i have.  my home windows box, for now.  not accessible to the outside world, yet.